# Deleting a tag on a question [tristana]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Someone asked the following question: [League of legends Tristana strategy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112846/league-of-legends-tristana-strategy)

He created a tag while doing so, [tristana]. First of all, I can't imagine how that tag would be usefull to the site. Therefore, I think the tag should be deleted. Is retagging (removing the tag) enough to accomplish so, or does something else have to happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing the tag from all questions effectively deletes it after a day or two.

See also the answer to "[How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/what-happens-to-zombie-tags)":

> Tags not associated with any question are pruned every 24 hours on the backend.
>
> Tag counts shown on the tags tab and in the tags autocomplete are also calculated once daily.

"Tristana" seems to be in this case a (playable?) character or character class. While I couldn't find any meta post qualifying if we want such tags, the fact that it's the first instance of such I know of *and* it isn't needed to find the question (the name is in the title as well) indicates that it can be safely deleted without compromising this site's usability or SEO strategy.

Comment: I agree that this tag should be deleted, but we do have character-specific tags. tf2-[class]

Comment: Pruning unused tags is disabled on Arqade, I believe.

Comment: I thought Arqade just didn't prune tags with *only one question* - tags that aren't on anything should still be removed, right?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Pruning "low activity" tags is disabled; pruning unused ones works just fine.

Comment: @Martin Excellent; that's good to know.